# Number Sub-Elements

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to show a XML "2D list" like this:

```
<list1>
  <list2>a</list2>
  <list2>b</list2>
  <list2>c</list2>
  <list2>d</list2>
</list1>
<list1>
  <list2>e</list2>
  <list2>f</list2>
  <list2>g</list2>
  <list2>h</list2>
  <list2>i</list2>
  <list2>j</list2>
</list1>
```

And I would like it to show like this:

```
01 a
02 b
03 c
04 d
05 e
06 f
07 g
08 h
09 i
10 j
```

What I thought initially was to have a xsl:variable outside the two for-each and to increment it but the variables are immutable.
How can this be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="list1/list2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//list2">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(position(), '00'), ' ', ., '&#10;')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The first rule matching the document root is not needed. The second rule doesn't output the desired result: `position` function is relative to the constext list, in this case all the sibilings `list2` elements from each `list1` father. In short, the enumeration will be restarted. Check in http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=b0eca037-034e-4796-998c-758523629638-xsltransformation

Answer (score 1):

No need for `xsl:variable` here, or even more than one `xsl:for-each` (or `xsl:apply-templates`). You can just select all `list2` elements at once, then use `position()` to get the numbering, because `position()` is based on the position of the node in the set of selected nodes, not the position in the document tree.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="list1/list2" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list2">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(position(), '00'), ' ', ., '&#10;')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes your XML is well-formed, and all the `list1` elements are in a single parent element.

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQf9

Comment: Correctly points to **context list** concept for `position` function.

Answer (score 1):

One more possible way to achieve it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="items" select="//list1/list2" />

    <xsl:for-each select="list1">
        <xsl:for-each select="list2">

            <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()" />
            <xsl:for-each select="$items">
                <xsl:if test="generate-id() = $id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',.)" />
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/eieE3Q8/1

Comment: A very unknowingly complex answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned using [`xsl:number`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#number). That's what I usually use when I have to number something like a list.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <list1>
        <list2>a</list2>
        <list2>b</list2>
        <list2>c</list2>
        <list2>d</list2>
    </list1>
    <list1>
        <list2>e</list2>
        <list2>f</list2>
        <list2>g</list2>
        <list2>h</list2>
        <list2>i</list2>
        <list2>j</list2>
    </list1>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (Works in other versions too.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="list2">
    <xsl:number level="any" format="01 "/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
01 a
02 b
03 c
04 d
05 e
06 f
07 g
08 h
09 i
10 j
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfa/1

Comment: Welcome back @Alejandro !